# Java TFS SDK can't authenticate user when code is deployed to tomcat server

Tags: tfs

I'm currently using the Java TFS SDK to connect to on-premise TFS 2012 server and it works but I need to use a newly added account to TFS.  When I run the code on my local machine it connects without issue. I can use both the original account and the new account.

When I deploy the code to my remote linux tomcat server and run it through a web service call, it fails to authenticate using the new account. It works when I use the original account, but I need it to work for this new account.

This is the error:

com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TFSUnauthorizedException: Access denied connecting to TFS server http://tfsserver:8080/ (authenticating as MYDOMAIN\new_account)

Here's how I connecting

```
        TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc;
        String tfsURL = "http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/My%20Software%20Development/";

        try {
            Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("MYDOMAIN\\" + TFS_USER, TFS_PASSWD);
            URI tfsURI = new URI(tfsURL);
            tpc = new TFSTeamProjectCollection(tfsURI, credentials);
            tpc.ensureAuthenticated();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Unable to connect to TFS at " + tfsURL + "; Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        }
```

Here's what I've tested:

- I can connect to TFS with this new account from Visual Code IDE on my desktop.
- I can connect to TFS with this new account from tomcat server running on my desktop
- I can connect to TFS with the OLD account from tomcat server running on remote server.
- I can NOT connect to TFS with this new account from tomcat server running on remote server.

So why would TFS deny authentication for this new account ONLY from the remote server?

Comment: Is your local machine also Linux? As far as I know, the linux machines are case sensitive. Please check the new account username. On the other hand, can only one old account be logged in? Do other users accounts(Exclude new account) in tfs have this problem?

Comment: No, my local machine is Win10. Its not a typo issue.